# Copying struct tm

Tags: c++, glibc, tm, time-t

The glibc version of struct tm has additional fields

```
long tm_gmtoff;           /* Seconds east of UTC */
const char *tm_zone;      /* Timezone abbreviation */
```

(Ref: http://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime )
My question is: If I have a data called struct tm a and i would like to copy that to another struct tm b, as per below code:

```
time_t t = time(0);
const tm *pa = localtime(&t);
struct tm a;
if(pa) {
    memcpy(&a, pa, sizeof(a));
}
```

But, what will happen to tm_gmtoff and tm_zone? How to copy these fields too?

Comment: Why do you think these two fields would not be copied?

Comment: Moved this to the answer...

Comment: For the interested, here is a modern, thread-safe, cross-platform, C++11/14/17 library for handling timezone-related issues: https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html

Answer (score 4):

This is a job for your compiler. It will take all necessary action.
Just do:

```
struct tm a = *localtime(&t);
```

Comment: Just for those curious about ownership: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8694379/978486

Comment: But  tm_zone being a character array, the copying will not be deep copy rather a shallow copy sharing the pointer

Comment: That is true. But what I read is that the timezone value is being ignored and the locale settings are used instead. Could be wrong here but I think thats how it works

Comment: Seems like this will crash in certain cases. Here a link to a reproducer: https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/-/issues/700#note_40990

Comment: So it clearly is a bad idea to do like suggested in this answer. Here some doc of localtime: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/localtime.html `.... If an error is detected, localtime() shall return a null pointer and set errno to indicate the error.` So if NULL will be returned by `localtime`, the suggested code will crash.

Answer (score 1):

Since `locatime()` may return a *null pointer*, avoid

```
const struct tm a = *localtime(&t);  // Potential UB.
```

Instead, test for null-ness and then copy with `=`.  `memcpy()` not needed.  All `struct tm` members will be copied.

```
struct tm a = { 0 }; // Fill in a default value
const tm *pa = localtime(&t);
if (pa) {
  a = *pa;
}
```

---

OP comments [But tm_zone being a character array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43677130/copying-struct-tm/70416050#comment74401623_43677269), yet that is amiss.  `tm_zone` is not a *character array*, but a pointer to a `const` character array.  Copying that pointer is fine here.

Comment: Not sure if it will be sufficiient to just copy the pointer of  tm_zone. That very much depends on the use-case ... the tm of the system will be changing, so will the time-zone on which we hold a pointer on. E.g. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026224/calling-time-in-c-changes-my-struct-tm

Comment: The pointer, in `*pa` or a copy of it in `a` certainly is valid up to the next `localitme()/gmtime()` call.  Up to that point, it is sufficient.  After that it may still be OK - an implementation specific issue that linux is silent on.  Code could `a = *pa;, a.tm_zone = strdup(pa->tm_zone);` and then manage the string.  Your point is valid, yet OP's use case lacks details.

Answer (score 0):

I think just `memcpy` is the right thing to do here for most cases.

> But, what will happen to tm_gmtoff and tm_zone? How to copy these fields too?

According to [the doc you linked](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime), these fields will only be present when `_BSD_SOURCE` was set before including `<time.h>`.

So if you are using `_BSD_SOURCE`, you will need to use `strcpy` on `tm_zone` after the `memcpy`.